# How do I bypass or create a database connection on iPad?

Tags: ios, mysql

I’ve tried several apps from the App Store but all require creating a Connection involving IP Address and host and so on, which I don’t have any idea about. I’d like something that just helps me start off without the need of a connection OR if anyone could assist me with connection details for practice. Thank you.

Comment: It is rare for a mobile application to make a direct connection to a remote database. Usually the mobile app connects to a webserver via http and the webserver makes the database connection. You  can alternatively use sqlite as a local, embedded database.

Comment: @Shadow thank you. Any tips on doing that, please? I’ve been so confused and not sure which app to use. They all seem to require subscriptions etc.

Comment: Doing what of the two options I described? What apps are you talking about?